adding remove button to the dynamically added row jquery
I want to add a delete row button to the dynamically generated rows that clears the result of the row from the total.
This is the code in jsfiddle
this is what i tried
$(document).on("click", ".delete-row", function () {

  
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      row--;
      calculate(elementID);
 
    return false;
 
  
  }); 
      ```


So, once you delete the row, get the total input value of the row, and then minus it from the sum
$(document).on("click", ".delete-row", function() {

  const tableRow = $(this).closest('tr')
  const total = +tableRow.find('[name="total"]').val()
  const sum = +$('#totalOfTotals').text();
  $('#totalOfTotals').text(sum - total);
  tableRow.remove();
  row--;
  calculate(elementID);

  return false;
});



thank you i applied your answer and it works great , can you please tell me how to prevent the delete button from appearing in the first (default) row i want it to show only in the added rows the link to the fiddle is above .
